# Is a contract valid on its "expiration date"

Tags: united-states, contract-law

I'm attempting to parse a US contract that states that its "expiration date" is 20th March 2021.
Ideally the contract itself would specify explicitly that either:

1. the expiration date is the first day on which the contract is *not* in force - meaning that the contract expires at midnight at the start of its expiration date, or
2. the expiration date is the last day on which the contract *is* in force - meaning that the contract expires at midnight at the end of its expiration date.

However, it does not.

In the absence of any such disambiguating text, is such a contract still in force on its "expiration date"? Is there statute or case law dictating this?

Comment: I've downvoted both answers here because neither of them provides any basis to believe that it is true, and clearly at least *one* of them is completely wrong (since the thesis of Dale's answer is that there *is* a precise convention on how to interpret such wording while the thesis of Iñaki's is that there is not).

Comment: "Is there statute or case law dictating this?": contracts are generally governed by state law, so there could be more than 50 different correct answers.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Iñaki's thesis is actually that the contract would override the general case, and so we can’t say for certain in a specific case without looking at the terms of that specific contract.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

In a normally drafted contract, dates are inclusive. So an “expiry date” is the last date the contract was in force, expiring just before midnight of the next day. Most contracts don’t usually need such precision in their timekeeping but some, such as contracts for financial products, do.

Of course, the contract can specify a different time, either specifically (3pm) or by reference to another event (close of business).

Comment: Source/prooflink? Also, you've lost one second between 23:59:59 and midnight. It still belongs to the previous day.

Comment: Greendrake, 23:59:59 is unambiguous. "Noon" is unambiguous. "Midnight" isn't. You could claim that "Midnight" is obviously at the start of the day, and I could claim that "Midnight" is obviously at the end of the day. Being unambigous is more important than the one second.

Comment: @gnasher729 the problem with "midnight" is that it is obviously a dimensionless point in time that separates one day from another.  The question with 23:59:59 would be whether it literally means that the contract expires at the dimensionless point in time one second before the end of the day or it is merely a figure of disambiguation. For example, if it were an insurance contract and a loss could be demonstrated to have occurred within the one-second period of time following 23:59:59, would it be covered?  I suspect we may never know.

Answer (score 0):

> In the absence of any such disambiguating text, is such a contract still in force on its "expiration date"?

One cannot answer in the affirmative or in the negative without assessing the contract altogether and perhaps the extrinsic evidence. If the matter is not ascertainable from elsewhere in the contract, the controversy would have to be decided via the [doctrine of *contra proferentem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem).

Comment: Why not articulate the reason or pretext for the downvote?

Comment: I am not the downvoter - I don't have the rep - but I suspect the downvote is because you've provided no sources to substantiate that what you claim in this answer is actually true. It seems plausible to me as a layman, but then it *also* seems plausible to me as a layman that there might be some convention, perhaps enshrined in statute, about how to interpret an "expiry date".

Comment: @MarkAmery "*there might be some convention*". There is none, and a law toward establishing a convention is likelier to do more harm than good because of the great variability of contracts as to their terms, nature, and circumstances. [*Partlow v. Matthews*, 43 Wn.2d 398, 407 (1953)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/195344143wn2d3981394) is an instance of a contract where, not being explicit in this regard, its termination is construed to "*become effective **on** the expiration date*" (emphasis added) rather than the day after. Yet that construction does not constitute binding precedent.